# Powershell script to remove weak ciphers

Tags: powershell, azure-web-roles, azure-powershell

is the below power shell scripts removes the weak ciphers and what I exactly want to remove are the below ciphers

- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
- TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA

PowerShell Script

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-ssl-configure/blob/22947a8ece9f7c1b2f1f5c5f28dbccf5ffb43952/AzureCloudServiceSample/WebRoleSample/Startup/SSLConfigure.ps1

your help is highly appreciated

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. You want us to tell you if a script works, possibly after modifying it? Any reason you don't try it yourself?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have tried it my self but it keeps getting error exit code 255